# Spring-boot datasource commit trouble

Tags: java, spring-boot, datasource

My application uses Spring-Boot 1.4.1.RELEASE and the configuration of my datasource is as follows;

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: ***
    username: ***
    password: ***
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    initial-size: 1
    max-active: 100
    max-idle: 30
    min-idle: 1
    max-wait: 0
    pool-prepared-statements: true
    max-open-prepared-statements: 3
```

The problem is that the last case of my integration testing if it contains a `@Sql` setup logic in it, fails to commit the last setup SQL. The trouble happens rarely due to the reordering of the cases, and the fact that there is only a handful cases with setup logic to prepare DB. There is no configuration but the one for the OracleDB, and that is in the `ConfigClass`.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = ConfigClass.class)
public class EtcTest {

    @After
    public void teardown() {
        // teardwon X, Y, & Z
    }

    @Test
    @Sql("setupX.sql")
    @Sql("setupY.sql")
    @Sql("setupZ.sql")
    public void get_fromDb() {
        List<Etc> list = buildExpectedList();
        Obj expected = buildExpected();
        Obj actual = getCallToAPI();

        assertThat(rs.getX()).isEqualTo(expected.getX());
        assertThat(rs.getY()).isEqualTo(expected.getY());
        assertThat(rs.getZ()).containsAll(list);
    }
}
```

The trouble, for example in the above case if it were the last integration case, 
that it fails to commit the last SQL in the `@Sql` annotations, namely `SetupZ.sql`, but the data is not completely missing, it inserts the primary key, and sometimes `columnA`, or `columnB`, it is as if something is really wrong here.

Would the presence or absence of some configuration cause this? If not what would be the reason?

Comment: If you're using auto-configuration, you should read [the release note](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes) when you upgrade, and in particular [this section](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes#datasource-binding). All the connection pool specific settings have moved to dedicated namespace. Review your configuration.

Comment: @StephaneNicoll I have been using the same version, the only change was that I've added some setup & teardown methods that are annotated with junit's before and after annotations. I've had a successful build last time when somehow the build put a non-db related test at the end, now I am again getting same non-commit issue with the last case again.

Comment: For Oracle 9i onwards you should use `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` rather than `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` as Oracle have stated that `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` is deprecated .

Comment: Are you using java 8 ?

Comment: Have you tried to make your test `@Transactional` ?? And if possible introduce `@Before` method with same `@SQL` annotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to some conflicting libraries within both JUnit & Spring/Hibernate. After updating to the latest Spring & Junit version & updating to Java8 the issue is gone.

Answer (score 2):

You can work with `@Transactional` tests. This allow you to run the test check the result and get BD rolled back to pre-test state.

Reference http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.11.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle#testcontext-tx-enabling-transactions

Answer (score 1):

Hi for test classes instead of actual database you can go with In-Memory databases like DB2,derby and h2. it provides the solution for your trouble.

for Code example you can find below URL (Stackoverflow link)
[Spring data jpa repository In-memory test case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38525784/3913948)

Answer (score 1):

You would try use JPA for persisting. The following settings would be available:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Then you could see what went wrong.